# Have to specify a value two time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a button that would move, first to the right, then to the left when pressed again.

After a lot of searching, I've been able to make it, but I have to declare it two times. Like, the code won't accept the `CSS` version.

Here's my code :

HTML

```html
 <div id="light"><div id="button"></div></div>
```

CSS

```css
padding: 10px;

#light {
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-top: 420px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 40px;
}
#button {
    width: 16px;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    left: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

JS

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.style.left = "4px";
button.onclick = function() {
    if (button.style.left === "4px") {
        button.style.left = "20px";
    } else {
        button.style.left = "4px";
    }  
}
```

[Here's the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8947feqg/27/)

If I delete the `button.style.left ="4px"` declaration from the JS, it wouldn't works because if I do `console.log(button.style.left)`, the result would be nothing.
And that's the thing I don't quite understand there.

Comment: Do you want something like that `if (button.style.left === "") { button.style.left = "20px";` you check if the style if defined (no need to force it to be 4px)

Answer (score 0):

"element.style" returns the inline style, but not the computed css.

Instead, you want to use : [window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");



            button.onclick = function() {
                if (window.getComputedStyle(button, null).getPropertyValue('left') === "4px") {
                    button.style.left = "20px";
                } else {
                    button.style.left = "4px";
                }  
            }
```

[Working JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/k78y2ghn/)

Comment: Ok, i though i could get the value from the css by there :/

Answer (score 0):

a) You should not use style, but instead use a class that you can toggle.

```
button.classList.toggle("to-right")
```

b) You should never do a transition over all values, but specify each value that you want to animate. Otherwise, CSS will loop through all animatable values, which can take time.

```
transition: 0.5s left
```

c) You should add the click listener on the #light container, not in the actual button, to achieve better accessibility. (Not implemented in code below)

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");


button.onclick = function() {
  button.classList.toggle("to-right")  /* == a == */
}
```

```css
#light {
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 10;
    /* margin-top: 420px;*/ 
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 40px;
}
#button {
    width: 16px;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    left: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.5s left;  /* == b == */
}

#button.to-right { /* == a == */
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="light"><div id="button"></div></div>
```

Comment: Looks clean, thanks.